# Server 2012 won't recognize raid harddrives

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I'm trying to install server 2012 on a Dell Poweredge 1850. I have setup the raid. The logical drive is active and functioning. I have tried using the 2003 drivers and still the OS does not recognize the drives when trying to install the OS.

Anybody know The correct Raid settings I need for the hard drives?

Answer (score 2):

2012 tends to need/want 2008/2012-specific drivers as its driver model has changed a LOT since 2003 - I'd say there's an almost-100% chance that the issue is you need the [2008/2012 driver set](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/uk/en/ukbsdt1/Product/poweredge-1850).

Comment: I have tried the 2008 drivers with no luck. can anyone point me to the 2012 drivers? Dell only have up to 2003 on their site

Comment: I'm pretty sure that server doesn't officially support 2012 - hence my recommendation to use the 2008 ones - if they don't support it you're out of luck sorry.